# Calculate edit distance percentage

Tags: r, bioinformatics, string-comparison, edit-distance

I am attempting to get a percentage of an edit distance from a group of sequences. So far this is what I have:

```
library(stringdist)

sequence <- c("CA--------W----------------------EKDRRTEAF---F------",
   "CA--------W----------------------EKDRRTEAF---F------", 
   "CA--------S-------------------SLVFGQGDNIQY---F------", 
   "RA--------S-------------------SLIYSP----LH---F------")

edit_dist <- stringdistmatrix(sequence)
#0 
#13 13 
#14 14 11

len <- stri_length(gsub('-', '', sequence))
#13    13    16    12
```

As each line of `len` is equivalent to each line of `sequence`, when comparing the two lines I would like to use the largest `len` to get the percentage. So as when having an edit distance between the second and third sequence it would use the length of 16 rather than 13 to get a percentage.

I know this code is wrong, but it is generally the idea I am going for:

```
for (i in len) {
  num1 <- len[i]
  for (j in len){
    num2 <- len[j] 
    if (num2 > num1){
        num <- num2
        }else{
          num <- num1
        }
    }
    edit_dist/num
}
```

The answer should look something similar to that below:

```
0
.8125  .8125
1.0769  1.0769  .6875
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct a suitable matrix of the max length with `outer` and `pmax`, which you can then coerce to `dist` class (like `edit_dist`) so you can divide:

```
edit_dist <- stringdistmatrix(sequence)
n <- nchar(gsub('-', '', sequence))

edit_dist / as.dist(outer(n, n, pmax))
##          1        2        3
## 2 0.000000                  
## 3 0.812500 0.812500         
## 4 1.076923 1.076923 0.687500
```